# Executing Docker Commands from one container to the other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers:

1. PHP container
2. PostgreSQL container

In my PHP script, I want to use the command \COPY from Postgres. However this cannot be executed in PHP since this command is native to Postgres.

In classic environments, not on docker, I could use the php function exec(PgSQL COMMMAND) and that would allow me to still execute my scripts. However in a docker environment, how do I execute this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It’s not possible. You would have to connect via SSH to the second container from the php one in the first place. Treat containers as separate and independent machines.

Comment: You should be able to use an ordinary PostgreSQL connection.  You won't necessarily be able to do a bulk `\COPY` but you can execute normal SQL `INSERT` commands to load data.  You do not need anything Docker-specific or a subprocess call to do this.